# Eliminate $A$ from these two equations.

Tags: trigonometry

$$x = \cot A + \tan A$$

$$y = \cos A + \sec A$$

Eliminate $A$ from these two equations.

We tried doing $y^2 - x^2$ but it did not eliminate $A$.

Comment: If the second equation has $\csc A$ in place of $\cos A$, then the answer would be $y^2-x^2$. Are you sure you don't have a transcription error?

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\cot A+\tan A=\frac1{\cos A\sin A}$$

Squaring we get
$$x^2\cos^2A(1-\cos^2A)=1\iff x^2\cos^4A-x^2\cos^2A+1=0\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$y=\cos A+\sec A\iff y\cos A=\cos^2A+1$$

Squaring & rearranging we get $$\cos^4A+(2-y^2)\cos^2A+1=0\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Solve $(1),(2)$ for $\displaystyle\cos^2A,\cos^4A$ and use $\displaystyle(\cos^2A)^2=\cos^4A$

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I think vinod is a better person to face this question?

Comment: sorry, I posted at the wrong place